TypeScript library and Worker
I'm working on an open source project, GraphAI, a declarative data flow programming environment. I'm adding a multi-threading capability to it so that any portion of the graph can be process by Worker threads. I was able to make it work with some hacks (hard-coded path to a generated JS file), but I am having a hard time in making it available as a part of this rpm package.
Here is the current code (the source code of this file is here).
    if (!isMainThread && parentPort) {
      const port = parentPort;
      port.on("message", async (data) => {
        const { graphData } = data;
        const graphAI = new GraphAI(graphData, vanillaAgents);
        const result = await graphAI.run();
        port.postMessage(result);
      });
    }
    
    export const workerAgent: AgentFunction<{ namedInputs?: Array<string> }, any, any> = async ({ inputs, params, /* agents, log, */ graphData }) => {
      const namedInputs = params.namedInputs ?? inputs.map((__input, index) => `$${index}`);
      namedInputs.forEach((nodeId, index) => {
        if (graphData.nodes[nodeId] === undefined) {
          // If the input node does not exist, automatically create a static node
          graphData.nodes[nodeId] = { value: inputs[index] };
        } else {
          // Otherwise, inject the proper data here (instead of calling injectTo method later)
          (graphData.nodes[nodeId] as StaticNodeData)["value"] = inputs[index];
        }
      });


    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const worker = new Worker("./lib/experimental_agents/graph_agents/worker_agent.js");
    worker.on("message", (result) => {
      worker.terminate();
      resolve(result);
    });
    worker.on("error", reject);
    worker.on("exit", (code) => {
      if (code !== 0) reject(new Error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`));
    });
    worker.postMessage({ graphData });
  });

};

I'd really appreciate any help, hint or suggestions.
